# How do I debug stuck rails process in development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm in the process of upgrading my old rails 4.2 app to rails 5. I'm currently trying to make it work at 5.1. When I try to access a page of my app in development, it seems to boot okay and it starts to render. By the browser never receives a response from the server and the server just stops outputting to the logs. I cannot figure out what is going on.

How can I further debug what why it hangs and never responds?

**Output of `rails s`:**

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.7 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 4.3.3 (ruby 2.6.5-p114), codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 1, max threads: 1
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:3000
* Listening on tcp://[::1]:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
I, [2020-04-27T15:18:05.059708 #75800]  INFO -- : [83adaf81-4bf7-4870-b5f8-b6c0c11a4d2b] Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-04-27 15:18:05 +0200
D, [2020-04-27T15:18:05.608709 #75800] DEBUG -- : [83adaf81-4bf7-4870-b5f8-b6c0c11a4d2b]    (3.6ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC /*application:MyApp*/
I, [2020-04-27T15:18:06.590249 #75800]  INFO -- : [83adaf81-4bf7-4870-b5f8-b6c0c11a4d2b] Processing by MyAppController#front_page as HTML
D, [2020-04-27T15:18:06.613950 #75800] DEBUG -- : [83adaf81-4bf7-4870-b5f8-b6c0c11a4d2b]   User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "da"."users".* FROM "da"."users" WHERE "da"."users"."auth_token" = $1 LIMIT $2 /*application:MyApp,line:/app/controllers/controller_concerns/session_handling.rb:35:in `current_user'*/  [["auth_token", "uWOt-zCVDbo8a6AT-SkWUQ"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
I, [2020-04-27T15:18:06.766078 #75800]  INFO -- : [83adaf81-4bf7-4870-b5f8-b6c0c11a4d2b]   Rendering myapp/front_page.html.haml within layouts/front_page
D, [2020-04-27T15:18:06.866720 #75800] DEBUG -- : [83adaf81-4bf7-4870-b5f8-b6c0c11a4d2b]   Car Load (3.1ms)  SELECT  "cars".* FROM "cars" WHERE "cars"."user_id" = $1 AND "cars"."sales_state" = $2 ORDER BY "cars"."id" DESC LIMIT $3 /*application:MyApp,controller:myapp,action:front_page,controller_with_namespace:MyAppController,line:/app/controllers/controller_concerns/user_listings.rb:11:in `last_on_hold_listing'*/  [["user_id", 900000000], ["sales_state", "on_hold"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2020-04-27T15:18:06.929863 #75800] DEBUG -- : [Redis] command=GET args="da/brands_and_model_names/v1.0"
D, [2020-04-27T15:18:06.932895 #75800] DEBUG -- : [Redis] call_time=2.90 ms
I, [2020-04-27T15:18:07.071685 #75800]  INFO -- : [83adaf81-4bf7-4870-b5f8-b6c0c11a4d2b]   Rendered partials/_extended_search_form.html.haml (193.3ms)
I, [2020-04-27T15:18:07.242322 #75800]  INFO -- : [83adaf81-4bf7-4870-b5f8-b6c0c11a4d2b]   Rendered partials/_front_page_featured_items.html.haml (160.4ms)
```

It just stops at the point where it looks to be done with the processing in rails and should ship the response to the browser. Instead it just hangs as if I had e.g. a `binding.pry` in the code - but I don't. And nothing is emitted in the logs. I even can't stop the server, I have to kill it manually. CPU of the ruby process is idle at 0%.

`rails console` works fine btw.

What else can I do to figure out where it's getting stuck?

**UDPATE**

I have a suspicion that it could have something to do with asset compilation. In my old rails 4.2 branch, after reaching the particular point in the log, it would start to compile the assets on the fly in development, however that does not happen in the rails 5.2 branch. Now when running: `bin/rails assets:precompile` I get:

```
yarn install v1.22.4
warning package.json: No license field
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
warning No license field
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
✨  Done in 0.72s.
yarn install v1.22.4
warning package.json: No license field
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
warning No license field
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
✨  Done in 0.60s.
rails aborted!
ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: [stdin]:1:1: unexpected //=
compile ((execjs):7528:19)
eval (eval at <anonymous> ((execjs):7539:8), <anonymous>:1:10)
(execjs):7539:8
(execjs):7545:14
(execjs):1:40
Object.<anonymous> ((execjs):1:58)
Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:39:in `exec'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:21:in `eval'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:46:in `call'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/coffee-script-2.4.1/lib/coffee_script.rb:78:in `compile'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/coffee_script_processor.rb:24:in `block in call'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/cache.rb:92:in `fetch'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/coffee_script_processor.rb:23:in `call'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:22:in `block in <class:CompositeProcessor>'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:33:in `call'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:182:in `load_from_unloaded'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:59:in `block in load'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:335:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:43:in `load'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `load'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:41:in `block in call'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:167:in `dfs'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:42:in `call'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:182:in `load_from_unloaded'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:59:in `block in load'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:335:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:43:in `load'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `load'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:32:in `block in call'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:31:in `call'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:182:in `load_from_unloaded'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:59:in `block in load'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:335:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:43:in `load'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `load'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:81:in `find_asset'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:88:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in find'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:24:in `block in execute'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:41:in `block in synchronize'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:41:in `synchronize'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:41:in `synchronize'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:19:in `execute'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promise.rb:563:in `block in realize'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:353:in `run_task'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:342:in `block (3 levels) in create_worker'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:325:in `loop'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:325:in `block (2 levels) in create_worker'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:324:in `catch'
/Users/nielsk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@rails52/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:324:in `block in create_worker'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Could this maybe be something?

Comment: have u had a look inside the development.log file ? I suggest you check it if you did not you could find some errors that may be did not get printed to the terminal.

Comment: Nothing in there, same output

Comment: check the rendered partials like these shown in the log :
`Rendered partials/_front_page_featured_items.html.haml (160.4ms)` 
and see maybe some code inside them is causing infinite loop or by one way or another causing rails to freeze

Comment: try to request the same url with `curl` or different browser

Comment: Well, as those files have already been reported rendered in the log, they are not causing any infinite loops I guess.... So it must be somewhere else

Comment: does the code makes a request to a url or some other service and did not get the result back causing rails to wait forever

Comment: Nope. Also `curl` gives the same

Comment: Does it behaves the same on other pages of the app? Did you change anything in ApplicationController during the upgrade?

Comment: Okay, normally after that point it gets to in the logs (In my rails 4.2 branch) it would start to compile assets on the fly in development. That does not happen in the rails 5.2 branch. This leads me to think it has something to do with asset compilation. When running `bin/rails assets:precompile` I get: `ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: [stdin]:1:1: unexpected //=
compile ((execjs):7528:19)` and no application level stack trace

Comment: @Vasilisa it's the same on all pages

Comment: What do you have in config.assets.js_compressor option?

Comment: I have `config.assets.js_compressor=:uglifier`

Comment: I am guessing you are using the new ES6 javascript syntax in some code snippet which is not yet compatible with asset pre-compilation using sprockets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether you are using the `//=` syntax to require files in your CoffeeScript files. Apparently that is not supported anymore in sprockets 4.

You should replace all `//=` in .coffee files with `#=`

Disclaimer: I'm working on the same project as OP :)